# how to use wget with Many URL's in .txt file to download and save as

Tags: linux, ubuntu, url, download, wget

i have a txt file with too many direct links to be downloaded including each names of the files in front of each url, the txt file looks like:

```
http://example.com/file1.png name_of_the_file1
http://example.com/file2.mp4 name_of_the_file2
http://example.com/file3.mkv name_of_the_file3
http://example.com/file4.png name_of_the_file4
http://example.com/file5.avi name_of_the_file5
```

As you can see the filename and url are separated by space.

what I want is a linux command that enters the txt file containing the urls and download each file and then rename them to their respective name using `wget`.

Please help me, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**Note1: there is exactly one space between the url and filename**

**Note2: the filename may contain spaces: See example bellow**

```
http://example.com/47188.png Abaixo de Zero (2021)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what "*special characters*" can appear in a file name. Can a file name contain a space? Is there exactly one space between URL and file name?

Comment: yes there is exactly one space between the url and filename, as you proposed i edited the question to best explain the format of the url and filename in the txt file. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use this awk|xargs one-liner:**

```
awk '{url=$1; $1="";{sub(/ /,"");out=url" -O \""$0"\""}; print out}' file.txt | xargs -L 1 wget
```

Explanation:

```
    url=$1 # temp var inside awk
    $1="" # replace url with null space
    {sub(/ /,"");out=url" -O \""$0"\""} # need to output var
        sub(/ /,"") # need to trim leading white space
        out=url" -O \""$0"\"" # line formatting with escaping characters
    print out # シ
    xargs -L 1 wget # get awk output line by line to wget
plus some awk sintax sugar
```

Example:

```
cat << EOF >> file.txt
https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.1/openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz name_of_the_file2
https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.1/openssl-1.1.1j.tar.gz name of_the_file3
https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.1/openssl-1.1.1i.tar.gz name of the_file4
https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.1.1/openssl-1.1.1h.tar.gz name of the file5
EOF
awk '{url=$1; $1="";{sub(/ /,"");out=url" -O \""$0"\""}; print out}' file.txt | xargs -L 1 wget
ls -1
```

```
name_of_the_file2
'name of_the_file3'
'name of the_file4'
'name of the file5'
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, it worked like a charm...

Comment: Hi  Илья Бугримов  once again, after tested the command and working correctly, i wanted to know if it's possible to maintain each file extension when renaming? i guess is something that we can modify in the command , but don't know where. thanks again! regards.

Comment: Hi @RALPHBURAIMO you can use another variable in awk for file format, but it indeed need much more experiments. 
For easy apply capable you can first use awk/sed... for adding file extensions to end of each line, and it another question =)

Comment: Hi  Илья Бугримов  thanks once again...how could i do this in the command?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I can think of is the following simple python script:

```
import os
lines = open('<name_of_your_file>').readlines()
for line in lines:
    url, file_name = line.strip().split(' ', 1)
    os.system(f'wget {url} -o {file_name}')
```

If one wants it in a one liner bash, the following works:

```
$ python -c "import os; lines = open('<name_of_your_file>').readlines(); [ os.system(f'wget {url} -o {file_name}') for url, file_name in [line.strip().split(' ', 1) for line in lines]]"
```

Comment: Hi avika81, thanks for your quick response , but it seems not to work..i dont know if i'm doing something wrong, but the only thing i did is create a new file called down.py and then past the code there, but for some reason i got errors, i'm attaching the error screenshot in this link: https://i.imgur.com/GHu0lNX.png

Comment: The error here is that in the input txt file there is no space on one of the lines (maybe you have an empty line or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use  this code:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
        IFS=' '
        read -a strarr <<< "$line"
        wget -O ${strarr[1]} ${strarr[0]}
done < filename.txt
```

it's a bash scripts . But if you don't know how to use it:

1. Paste it in a file.sh
2. run this command in order to be able to execute: `chmod +x file.sh`
3. execute: `./file.sh`

P.S don't forget to change filename to use actual filename that contains links.

Comment: Hi devOps, thanks for your reply, i tested your solution and it seems to work but not completely, the script only picks the first string of the filename to rename it, while it must pick the whole name... see example : The filename is *abaixo do zero 2021*, so the script picks only the string abaixo and then it renames the file to be downloaded.

Comment: So as I understood the filename after link might contain more than one word? So sad, I didn't consider such a case. I will try to update my code . Will be glad if this code helped you a little bit

Answer (score 0):

```
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        IFS=' '
        read -a strarr <<< "$line"
        if [[ ${#strarr[@]} -gt 2 ]]
        then
                filename=''
                for (( i=${#strarr[@]}; i>0;  i-- ));
                do
                        filename="${strarr[i]} $filename"
                done
                wget ${strarr[0]} -O "$filename"
        else
                wget ${strarr[0]} -O ${strarr[1]}
        fi
done < filename.txt
```

This code was modified and now it's able to create files containing more than one word in filename. But this code is not very clear because I don't know all features of bash scripts . I'm actually using python.

Comment: Hi defvOps the code now seems to work perfectly, i wanted to know if it's possible to keep each file extension when renaming? thanks again!